# More than 4,294,967,296 in C?

Tags: c, fibonacci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“BigInt” in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c)

Hey there!
I'm calculating the Fibonacci numbers in C up to 46 using an **unsigned int**, but I can't calculate F(47) because it's long. So, is there a way to get numbers bigger than 2^32 in C?
NB: I use a 32-bit processor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**(unsigned) long long**, but it's also limited (to 2^64). If it's not enough, you need to look for a **BigInt** library.

Comment: Of course, on x86 and some other architectures, you can push it to 128 bits with a `__uint128_t`...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t my64bit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using 64-bit unsigned integers (check your C implementation for support), or simply use a BigNum package like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

In the past, I've made BigNum libraries myself for various purposes but GMP blows my meagre efforts out of the water.

Answer (score 1):

I love the answer given by user R.. for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c/3341363#3341363) to operate on bigints. Of-course you have to implement your own add function if you want to scale it to very large numbers. It explains the steps very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own data type that is able to hold big numbers or use a library such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bignlibacbignum/).