# Factorial calculation : unsigned long long overflows, How to use uintmax_t?

Tags: c, factorial

calculating a factorial in this method :

```
unsigned long long factorial(int n){
    unsigned long long temp = 1L;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        temp *=(n - i);
    }
    printf("\n%d factorial is %llu",n,temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Allows calculation upto `20!` only.

```
20! = 2432902008176640000 << 2^64
21! = 51090942171709440000 >> 2^64
```

I'v never used `uintmax_t` and reading from a few other SO articles , it all feels really complicated to use. If anyone could give some simple snippets as how to use and print them , it would be a major help.

**Edit** Regarding Didier Trosset's question , i thought that surely 20 wont be the limit upto which people can calculate a factorial in C. I was reading that uintmax_t is the biggest data type , so i thought it may be 128bits or something. So i wanted to use it.

Also , I didn't know about big int libraries in C. Sorry if i created a duplicate post.

Comment: `uintmax_t` isn't going to help - you need to look at using a suitable bit integer library.

Comment: May be [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) ?

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [What is the simplest way of implementing bigint in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c) and ["BigInt" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c)