# Why does my function returns a negative number when I'm adding positive numbers?

Tags: c++

I got this function that calculates factorial given an integer number:

```
long iterFact(long number) {
    long factorial = 1;

    for (long i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        factorial *= i;

    return factorial;
}
```

But it returns a negative number when I pass for example `20` as a parameter, I thought it would be because the number gets too long, but I'm still getting a negative number as result even after changing everything from `int` to `long`.

Comment: Integer overflow. Also, it's factorial not Fibonacci.

Comment: Because factorial grows rapidly and breaks the integer limit.

Comment: _"I thought it would be because the number gets too long, but I'm still getting a negative number as result even after changing everything from int to long"_ `long` isn't infinite either. Instead of guessing, examine each value and find out whether your types are big enough or not

Comment: Please look at the numbers. `2**63` is `9223372036854775808`. Now `19!` is `121645100408832000` (smaller) but `20!` is `2432902008176640000` (larger). Do you see the problem?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm afraid you are mistaken: `2432902008176640000` is smaller than `9223372036854775808`, so it fits in `long long`.

Comment: @chqrlie indeed thank you. But OP said it breaks at `20!` which was the source of my confusion. 64-bit breaks at `21!`

Answer (score 3):

You are not *adding* numbers, but instead multiplying them. Indeed you are not computing the Fibonacci sequence, but the factorials ;-)

Factorials grow very fast: 20! (`2432902008176640000`) does not fit in a `long` on your system (32 bits, probably Windows), so one of the multiplications causes an arithmetic overflow, which the C Standard explicitly describes as undefined behavior. On your system, the computation might be performed modulo 2^32 and the result could be a negative number, but this is not guaranteed by the Standard.

Switching to type `unsigned long long`, which is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits, will let you compute `20!` but will fail soon after, for `21!`. In fact `2432902008176640000` is slightly smaller than 2^63-1, so type `long long` would suffice too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean factorials, not the fibonacci sequence?

On most modern systems, `int` and `long` are both 32 bits, which can represent numbers up to about 2 billion. 20 factorial is about 2 billion billion. Try using `long long` which is 64 bits.

Comment: _"On most modern systems"_ On most modern _commodity_ systems. The majority of modern systems developed on today actually have 16 bit `int`. Best to avoid these sort of statements altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

That's an integer overflow ; since your variable is signed, and since the sign bit is the most significant one, at some point you overflow your variable. Actually, 20! is a huge number. You should try to declare your variable as unsigned long, and print it as such.

Comment: Randomly guessing is not a solution for a problem caused by randomly guessing.

Comment: This is **one** possible explanation. But as signed integer overflow invokes undefined behaviour, there are numerous other reasons.

Comment: Sorry for the poor answer, I'll be more careful before answering questions in the future. And thanks for the precision, i wasn't conscious an overflow induced an undefined behavior, i thought the most significant bits were just getting ignored,, but the least ones remained coherent ; i ran few tests on my machine to observe, and yes, there's no apparent logic in the results.

Answer (score 0):

If `sizeof(long)` is 4 bytes and LONG_MAX is 2^31 - 1 then there'll be integer overflow when you calculate `13!`. Signed integer overflow is [*undefined behaviour*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) You can use a different data type, such as `uintmax_t`, which can hold bigger numbers but still wouldn't be enough for handling bigger factorials.

Have a look at [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/).

Also: [What is the simplest way of implementing bigint in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c)

Comment: A 32 bit `long` cannot hold `2**32 - 1`!

Answer (score 0):

this is **overflow** of signed type

**int** could be 4 bytes: -2 147 483 648   /   2 147 483 647

**long** could be 8 bytes: -9223372036854775808 / 9223372036854775807

int/long could be signed and unsigned

Comment: In the OP's case, `long` is not 64-bits, but probably just 32-bit, hence the arithmetic overflow.

Comment: `int` could be 1 byte or 37 bits, etc. And neither `int` nor `long` can be unsigned.