# handle snippet code wrtten in C for large numbers

Tags: c, gcc, biginteger, bignum

I wrote this snippet code as a solution for a problem but in a test case that tries big numbers as input(for example 10000000000 10000000000 1), a weird output comes out.it's work for integer range number but how can I handle code for big numbers?

here's the  condition: (1 ≤  n, m, a ≤ 10^9).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m, n, a;
    int count = 1;

    scanf("%d%d%d",&m,&n,&a);

    if (m%a != 0) {
        count *= ((m/a)+1);
    }
    else {
        count *= (m/a);
    }

    if (n%a != 0) {
        count *= ((n/a)+1);
    } else {
        count *= (n/a);
    }

    printf("%d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

you can see the problem [here](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/A)

ps 1: my compiler is GNU GCC 5.1.0.

ps 2: I submit it to website compiler so can't install any foreign library.

Comment: How big do you need to go? The problem is likely that you're overflowing 32-bit ints for m, n and a. Would 64-bit values do (you have a long long already here!), or do you need arbitrarily large numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way of implementing bigint in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c)

Comment: you might need to use `scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&m,&n,&a);` when you change the definition of your variables to `long long int m, n, a;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `long long` data type instead of `int`. Because a signed 32-bit integer can handle upto `2^31 - 1`(i.e **32,767**) and `unsigned int` can reach upto **65,535**.

Also even if the integers are within `int` range you should use `long long` in contests on **codeforces** in case of multiplication. See example for better explanation.

```
Example:

m: 100000
n: 100000
a: 1
count = 1

From your code,
count *= m/a; // count *= 100000/1 = 100000
Now,
count *= n/a; // count *= 100000/1 = 10000000000(10^10);
10^10 is beyond 32 bit int range so you will get a wrong answer -_-
So use long long to avoid such overflow errors
```

Read more about [Data Type Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

If you wish, you can reduce your code length, like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long m, n, a, count1 = 1, count2 = 1;
    scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&m,&n,&a);
    count1 *= (m/a);
    count2 *= (n/a);
    if (m%a != 0) count1++;
    if (n%a != 0) count2++;
    printf("%lld", count1*count2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 32767 and 65535 are 16-bit not 32. His question says 10^9 which does fit into 2*31, it's just his example 10^10 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers are bigger than 64 bits, you will have to use a bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). On Debian-based Linux systems, you can install with `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`. Then, just include `gmp.h` and read up on [the docs](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Functions.html).

The first portion of your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void) {
    mpz_t m, n, a;
    mpz_init(m); //allocate memory for the mpz_t
    mpz_init(n);
    mpz_init(a);

    mpz_inp_str(m, stdin, 10); //variable, input stream, base
    mpz_inp_str(n, stdin, 10);
    mpz_inp_str(a, stdin, 10);

    mpz_t count;
    mpz_init_set_ui(count, 1); //count = 1

    mpz_t result;
    mpz_init(result);

    mpz_mod(result, m, a); //result = m % a
    if(mpz_cmp(result, 0) != 0) { //result == 0
        mpz_tdiv_q(result, m, a); //integer truncated division: result = m / a
        mpz_add_ui(result, result, 1); // result += 1;
        mpz_mul(count, count, result); // count *= result;
    }

    //the rest of the code 

    mpz_clear(m); //clean up
    mpz_clear(n);
    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(count);
    mpz_clear(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your compiler defines `int` as having 32-bit storage, then you can handle positive numbers up to `2^31-1`.

If you need to go further, e.g. up to `2^64-1`, consider using a (possibly unsigned) type that can handle bigger integers -- see for instance the [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) if you have C11.

If you need unbounded integers, then the problem is much more complex. The easiest you can do in this case is use a library, e.g. like the [GNU multiple precision arithmetic library](https://gmplib.org/):

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface.

Comment: the problem is if I define my count variable as long long int , the output for the small numbers will be wrong.

Comment: It shouldn't be wrong? There's no reason a 64-bit variable can't work with smaller numbers.