# how create and save more than 10^18 Integer Data Type?

Tags: c, types

unsigned long long data type have max range up to **18446744073709551615**

```
unsigned long long ll = 18446744073709551615;
```

how to create integer data type to save more than 10^18 value?

Comment: With a 128-bit integer (if available) or a big integer library. Related is [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc)

Comment: Time for "bignums". Know the limits of your integer types.

Comment: If you are working on some online judge problem or other automatically graded problem, the problem is probably intended not to be solved with big integers but with thought and analysis that figures out a way to avoid them.

Comment: You would first need enough memory to handle 4 quintillion bytes, and addressing capability to reference them all.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/biginteger-in-c).