# Use of bigint in C (Example using libtomath library)

Tags: c, math, biginteger, bigint

I want to use large integer to do some computation similar to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){
  long a = 123456789123456789123456789123456789;
  long b = 2*b;

  printf("%ld", a);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%ld",b );
  return 0;
}
```

which currently generates:

```
main.c:4:12: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer
      type
  long a = 123456789123456789123456789123456789;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I know there is a library called [libtomath](http://%20https://www.libtom.net/LibTomMath/) as pointed by this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c) but I could not find any example and and I'm new to C and don't know how to read through a library to find the answer. How could I modify the code using libtomath (or other solutions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use [`gmp`](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Esrirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html).

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_t x,y,two;
    if (argc<3)
        return 1;
    mpz_init_set_str (x, argv[1], 10);
    mpz_init_set_str (y, argv[2], 10);
    mpz_init_set_ui(two, 2U);
    mpz_add (x,x,y);/*x<-x+y*/
    mpz_mul (y,y,two);/*y<-y+y*/
    printf("%s\n", mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, x));
    printf("%s\n", mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, y));
    return 0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
% gcc addbig.c -lgmp
% ./a.out 49378437483789437894739874389\ 
          74387438978437894378743874837
123765876462227332273483749226
148774877956875788757487749674
% ./a.out 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\
          2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
```

Comment: GMP also has a [nice online reference manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/) or a [PDF version](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.2.1.pdf) if that is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can process `bn.tex` file given @ https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/tree/develop/doc to generate PDF docs of `libtomath`. If you cannot do that let me know and I will generate PDF for you.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @shiv. I downloaded the repo and tried to compile the `bn.tex` with `pdflatex bn` but it threw me an error `! LaTeX Error: File 'bn.ind' not found.`. Indeed I could not find that file

Comment: Let me process it for you.

Comment: Try downloading from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gw5_KCxmgd9u-F_hKU-2SBJrbNwmz-24/view?usp=sharing

Comment: many thanks! @Shiv. You didn't have `File 'bn.ind' not found` problem. Could you find that file?

Comment: `bn.ind` file or `*.ind` file are index files in LaTeX which are generated by `makeindex` program. Check your os for `makeindex` program.

Comment: @ecjb Can you please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation @Shiv. Your answered helped and therefore I upvoted it and I'm currently reading the .pdf. But the problem itself is not solved yet (i.e. there is no running code yet)

Comment: @ejcb I am a bit occupied right now. I will post a working example once I am free.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm also trying to find a solution. Many thanks again for your time so for