# Finding the 1500000th Fib Number Using C++

Tags: c++, numbers, int, fibonacci

I wrote the following code to find the 1500000th Fibonacci number(Please ignore horrible indenting, I wrote this in about 2 minutes). I need it as a string. This should, hypothetically work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int i;
int b=1;
int c=2;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int fib=1500000;

for (i=1;i<fib-3;i++){
c=b+c;
b=c-b;
}
   stringstream ss;
   ss << c;
   string d=ss.str();
cout << d << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It goes through the process 1500000-3 times(It goes over by 3 numbers every time)
I understand that the problem is that the number is to big to be contained as an int. Is there any way for me to store it without containing it as an int or file(Since that would be grossly inefficient)? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: You need all 250,000-odd digits of the answer to be exact?

Comment: Yep. I actually need every 20,000th digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Bignum library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum).

Comment: @jwodder: Might as well have said "use GMP".

Comment: @nightcracker : Why? There are decent alternatives, especially if you're using Windows or licensing is a concern. Boost.XInt comes to mind.

Comment: So there are no native solutions?

Comment: @TimeCoder: Other than writing your own Bignum library (not that great of an idea), no.

Comment: Well, you don't need to write an *entire* bignum library. Just allocation, addition, and conversion to string. If you use a base 10 representation, the last part doesn't require division or anything. But it's not a good route if you can avoid it.

Comment: @jwodder please provides an explanation of the Bignum library and what capabilities it provides in terms of multi-precision mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an exact form, you might use one of the other recurrence relations with a bignum library:

```
fib(2*n) = fib(n)^2 + fib(n-1)^2
fib(2*n-1) = fib(n)*(2*fib(n-1)+fib(n))
```

Which should reduce the number of calculations needed to O(log(n)) rather than O(n)
You can see pseudocode for a method based on this here: [nth fibonacci number in sublinear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525521/nth-fibonacci-number-in-sublinear-time/1526036#1526036)

Note that the n^th fibonacci number requires about n*log(phi)/log(2) = n*0.69 binary digits to represent, so exact representation of the 1.5M^th will require about 130kb to represent in binary, or 300kb as a string ( being approximately 2^(10000000) or 10^(300000) )

---

Removed as doubles overflow at about n=1500

You can do this directly using doubles as follows ( adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number ) :

```
double fib( int n )
{
   static const SQRT_5 = sqrt(5.0);
   static const phi = (1.0+SQRT_5)/2.0;
   return floor( (pow(phi,n)/SQRT_5) + 0.5 );
}
```

Although if you need every digit, this wont work. ( It will only give every digit upto about the 78th fibonacci number)

Comment: Well, nice hack, but AFAIK a Fibonacci number is an integer.

Comment: In general doesn't give the required precision, in this particular case overflows DBL_MAX.

Comment: Actually its worse than that ... it overflows at about the 1500th fibonacci number.

Comment: However it should give exact results up to about the 78th (which is near the size of the smallest integer not representable exactly as a double)

Answer (score 0):

The 1500000th Fibonacci number is printed in **C99** using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888675/18765627) with just a change :

```c
#define BUFFER_SIZE 18935
```

There is no library, output should be like (313,482 digits) :

```c
129089216811873951612785 ... 853738956168354898000000
took 59s
```

Computation of **f(1500000)** took 30s and **base conversion** too, so it's about a minute.

**And** : *In 1963 Stephen P. Geller used an IBM 1620 computer to show that the last four digits repeat every 15,000 times, the last five repeat every 150,000 times, and finally, after the computer ran for nearly three hours, a repetition of the last six digits [appeared](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/1-2/geller.pdf) at the 1,500,000th Fibonacci number.*

Try [f(15000)](https://tio.run/##hVVtU9pAEP6eX7GDUycpiYCUVhu0Uyu2tvZNa190GOZILnA1JDS5qOjw2@lejou5IG0@MGR3b@95dp/deM7I8xaLDRZ5YeZT6KbcZ/HWeN/QTCEbCpux4dOARRQOzo@OeqeDs@OLHrR2dtudiqd3ODh4fdYDs3VyAt0udDqWYaQ8yTwOwywIaAL3BuCTsjs64MAin966uSWMo5H8YREHn3ByWbqt7xpz1zCuY@ajn/GBzGbquZ8u/9iVbJElb5VeZz@/FvY0OhJFECemG7lFZI7DcbSDfTwZwROdso2mxp5usxD0EnMQzgbE99fAVqi9OEo5VJxeyGjErWXhdGIEoTRdraJoMcu8HGhZBTcwXYzY3wOZdEnIBcdhVh4jHlNkNbUKsP5jpnqR5sFCLAv2FQIlB4HBgs3N1RTOaslKUEmlEetgEMuWqKuuNUhewf9wwEto2nlZJCAWgFmvM@jqGrJWJMXynhdDVMNmsmi0Na4ZRqMBsziDSYY9DhJKgY8pJJRnSUR9kIFAAo5Nz1Iyojg4hDMPvDFBGfB4IEOUhh4VC@hSEhoZkpQO4qxQkMqaB8jcJJyOyZByxF9rtrbbzzrPX@zsvj54c9g7evvu@P2Hk4@fPn/5enr27fz7j5@/LsjQw7Efjdnvq3ASxdM/Scqz65vb2V1NEyOxYYhQMG3LBl@65I0p2iYkDGPP9LCBSqLIxpvOzNRGHLWyFkrq1iou5Nwtz7EL2CZFtTj@iDYQGho9VJhbDhePL1RmSqAWTOjEGyemqpENqVgI4nxRWAeU18IW6EJCdbpa9vRyKGSsTlz6uEpUqr4eKmD70CjcD9558e9mzEKKDKskRIUTKkuM9azXy3VWD3KbxNfUTIUPmWGzKhF5pwqs5F9Ycf2tAyp/pdYhFSOyENKcEBaZYj8u9zNOCCKKk1neNTEebYiyyZAmKbAUcjKE47DEUe5FKXtXW0o5pTmQhwYtxH7fnNvqfbvy3pbvyxEvfVY2VQIbmtZ697atL1fBieUrOZdlq9NsNlcEWbpb3fJQrsp3ooSjuLPUoBItldUt1VsqWJQGA1b2Ryl3C0mK4mPnppnYGnkj0ZynQVMqvliKKa6u5et88Rc) online - Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost](https://www.boost.org) makes using bignums extraordinarily easy.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_int integer;

integer fibonacci( unsigned long long n )
{
  integer a = 0;
  integer b = 1;
  while (n --> 0)
  {
    integer c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  return a;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
try
{
  long long n = std::stoll( argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "" );
  if (n < 0) throw 1;
  std::cout << fibonacci( n ) << "\n";
}
catch (...)
{
  std::cerr << 
    "usage:                                     \n"
    "  fibonacci N                              \n"
    "where N is the Fibonacci number to compute.\n";
  return 1;
}
```

In the example above I have used the native Boost bignum type, which is:

- header only (no need to compile Boost!)
- pretty darn quick
  — I computed fibonacci(1500000) in about two minutes on my *ancient* AMD Sempron 130. If I knock off a zero the results are almost instantaneous.

If that isn’t fast enough for you, [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) also provides backends for:

- [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org)
  This is the best bignum library out there, used in almost all serious bignum computing contexts, but it is encumbered by copyleft and is notoriously difficult to set up properly.
- [libTomMath](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath)
  This is significantly easier to install, but you still must know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `C++` is fast at all ?

```
    gawk  -v _____='1500000' -v PREC=20000 -p- -Mbe '

    BEGIN {
     1      _ += ___ = _ ^= ____ = __ = _ < _
     1      _____ += ___
     1      ____ = --_____
     1      do {
     1          print __ = length(_ = fib(____)), substr(_, 1, 50), substr(_, __ + 1 - 50)
        } while (++____ < _____)
    }

     1  function fib(______, _, __, ___, ____, _____)
    {
     1      if ((______ = +_ < ______ ? +______ : +_) < (__ *= (__ = _ ~ _) + (++__))) {
            return (______ - ((! _) < (______ % --__)))
        }
     1      _____ = (___ = __ = (_ = _ < _) ~ _) + ___
    20      while ((___ += ___) <= ______) {
    20          ++____
        }
    21      do {
    21          __ = (__ * __ + _ * _) substr(_ *= __ + __ - _, ___, ! ___)
    21          if (int(______ / (___ /= _____)) % _____) { # 10
    10              __ = (__ + _) substr(_ = __, ___, ! ___)
            }
        } while (____--)
     1      return _
    }
( gawk -v _____='1500000' -v PREC=20000 -p- -Mbe ; )  0.10s user 0.01s system 95% cpu 0.115 total

 313482 12908921681187395161278531776694736120150441703840        
        02113051432895630172796932853738956168354898000000
```

*How the heck `C++` took ***59.0 secs*** for something `awk` takes **0.115  secs**